# Page Not Found "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2458

Tags: python, django

This is my project urls.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import re_path, include
from website.views import *
from website import urls as website_urls
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static 

        urlpatterns = [
    
              re_path(r'^/', include(website_urls)),
              re_path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls)
    ]
    
        if  settings.DEBUG:
    
            urlpatterns.extend(static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT))
```

This is my apps urls.py file

```
from django.urls import re_path
from .views import *

    
        urlpatterns = [
    
            re_path(r'^$', home, name='home'),
            re_path(r'^placeorder/<str:i>/$', PlaceOrder, name='placeorder'),
            re_path(r'^login/$', LoginPage, name='loginpage'),
            re_path(r'^logout/$/', Logout, name='logout'),
            re_path(r'^register/$', RegisterPage, name='register'),
            re_path(r'^addproduct/$', AddProduct, name='addproduct'),
        
    ]
```

This is my views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout,authenticate
from .forms import *
from django.http import HttpResponse
    
    
        def home(request):
    
            products = Product.objects.all()
            return render(request, 'website/home.html', {'products': products})
    
    
        def PlaceOrder(request,i):
    
             customer  = Customer.object.get(id=i)
             form = CreateOrderForm(instance=customer)
             if(request.method=='POST'):
                 form  = CreateOrderForm(request.POST, instance=customer)
                 if(form.is_valid()) :
                 form.save()
                 return redirect('/')
             return redirect(request, 'website/placeorder.html', {'form':form})
        
    
        def AddProduct(request):
    
             form = CreateProductForm()
             if (request.method=='POST'):
             form = CreateProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
                if (form.is_valid()):
                    form.save()
                    return redirect('/')
             return render(request, 'website/addproduct.html', {'form': form})
    
    
        def RegisterPage(request):
    
             if request.user.is_authenticated:
                return redirect('home')
             else:
                 form = CreateUserForm()
                 customerform = CreateCustomerForm()
                 if request.method == 'POST':
                    form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
                    customerform = CreatePostForm(request.POST)
                    if form.is_valid():
                         user = form.save()
                         customer = customerform.save(commit=False)
                         customer.user = user
                         customer.save()
                         return redirect('login')
                
                 return render(request, 'website/register.html', {'form': form},{'customerform': 
                 customerform})
            
            
        def LoginPage(request):
    
             if request.user.is_authenticated:
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                 if request.method == 'POST':
                       username = request.POST.get('username')
                       password = request.POST.get('password')
                       user  = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
                       if user is not None:
                         login(request, user)
                         return  redirect('/')
                 return render(request, 'website/login.html', {})
    
        def Logout(request):
    
             logout(request)
             return redirect('/')
```

I have shared the code of my views file, the URLs file of the project, and the URLs file of my app, and also shared my error. See and check what is the problem. This is my Django Project and its name is Online Shopping and there is an app in this project whose name is website .........

Comment: Try to change re_path(r'^/', include(website_urls)) to re_path(r'^$', include(website_urls)). Did this solve the problem?

Comment: no after doing this error comes No Reverse Match at /

Comment: please post your home.html and the complete error trace for 'no reverse ....'